# Submit form with text and images to Laravel Controller via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Using Laravel 7
jQuery v3.4.1

I'm trying to send the content of a form via Ajax to a Laravel Controller. The form contains a text field and a file field . I wanted to find a way to send both types of fields in one request.

It looks like the content gets send but Laravel can't read it and returns an error.

My Ajax Code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
}); 
    
var form = $('form')[0]; 
var formData = new FormData(form);

    
    
$.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            method:'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {

             console.log(data);
                
            },
            error: function (error,jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                
                
              console.log(data.error);          
                
            }
        });
```

The Form

```
<form id="newProduct" action="{{route('Product.store',app()->getLocale())}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input name="title" maxlength="10" length="10" placeholder="Product Title" type="text" id="title" class="form-control>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="files" class="files">
</form>
```

The Laravel function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        dd($request->input->all());
}
```

The Data gets send via ajax , but somehow Laravel can't access it all. I get the following error message from Laravel **Call to a member function all() on null**  with a 500 Http Return code.

This is an extract from the http request send to Larval via ajax

**-----------------------------23552347725043592001228805073
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
sdf**

What has to be changed so Laravel can read the data ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $request->all() return for you?

Comment: Its `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Yes it was $request->all() and it does have all the input fields in it :D . Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, `$request->input` is not an attribute of the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class and so calling `all()` on it returns null, because it doesn't exist.

As you've discovered, all input can be retrieved with the `all()` helper function, `$request->all()`.

Alternatively, input can be retrieved individually with input applied as a function `$request->input('field')` or `$request->get('field')`. Where `$request->input()` can also get nested entries `$request->input('form.name')`, something `get()` cannot do.